# What was changed in upbound / provider-aws between 0.40 and 0.46.1

Tags: kubernetes, localstack, crossplane

I'm playing with crossplane with Localstack.
All worked fine if I'm just following Localstack [guide](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/crossplane/), but when I'm trying to upgrade provider version to 0.46.1 and create a bucket, I got observe failed:
failed to observe the resource: [{0 reading Amazon
S3 (Simple Storage) Bucket (crossplane-test-bucket): Forbidden: Forbidden\n\tstatus
code: 403

I assume, crossplane is trying to use real STS in newer version

I tried to update provider:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: provider-aws-s3
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-s3:v0.40.0 -> 0.46.1
EOF
```

with provider config:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: aws.upbound.io/v1beta1
kind: ProviderConfig
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  credentials:
    source: Secret
    secretRef:
      name: localstack-aws-secret
      namespace: default
      key: creds
  endpoint:
    hostnameImmutable: true
    services: [iam, s3, sqs, sts]
    url:
      type: Static
      static: http://10.100.100.1:4566
  skip_credentials_validation: true
  skip_metadata_api_check: true
  skip_requesting_account_id: true
  s3_use_path_style: true
EOF
```

When I'm using provider-aws-s3:v0.40.0 all works as expected, but I got stacked when upgrading.
Whether I expect all should work as expected after upgrade.

I'm using kind as local cluster (kind version 0.20.0)
Localstack (version 3.0.2)
latest crossplane (version 1.14.4)

Comment: https://github.com/upbound/provider-aws/issues/1063 This has the answers.